# MySQL- Count total records based on different values of same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

**table_user**

```
id                name                   status                     flag                   country
====================================================================================================
1                  AB                       1                          0                     US
2                  BC                       1                          0                     UK
3                  CD                       0                          0                     IN
4                  DE                       3                          0                     BR
5                  EF                       3                          0                     UK
6                  FG                       2                          0                     IN
7                  GH                       4                          0                     IN
```

I want to count the no. of records where

`status` = 1 as `totalactiverecords`,

`status` = 0 as `totalinactiverecords`,

`status` = 3 as `totalrecentactiverecords`,

`status` = 2 as `totalemailnotverifiedrecords`,

`status` = 4 as `totalemailverifiedrecords`,

, and `country` is `UK`, ***all in a*** **single **SELECT** statement**.

Is there any specific way to do it?

I have thought of something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalactiverecords  WHERE status=1 
        COUNT(*) as totalinactiverecordsWHERE status=0,
        COUNT(*) as totalemailnotverifiedrecords WHERE status=2,
        COUNT(*) as totalrecentactiverecords WHERE status=3,
        COUNT(*) as totalemailverifiedrecords WHERE status=4

FROM table_user where country=IN
```

,but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT count(case status when '1' then 1 else null end) as totalactiverecords,
    count(case status when '0' then 1 else null end) as totalinactiverecords,
    count(case status when '2' then 1 else null end) as totalemailnotverifiedrecords,
    count(case status when '3' then 1 else null end) as totalrecentactiverecords,
    count(case status when '4' then 1 else null end) as totalemailverifiedrecords 
FROM table_user where country='IN'
```

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly. But I still dont get the documentation where such examples are avialable

Comment: You're welcome. I'm here to help. The official Mysql docs are at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ . The examples are very simple and common but you can find references to all Mysql features so you can compose them to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `CASE WHEN` in this kind of problem:

```
SELECT sum(case when status = 1 then 1 end) as totalactiverecords,
COUNT sum(case when status = 0 then 1 end) as totalinactiverecords,
COUNT sum(case when status = 2 then 1 end) as totalemailnotverifiedrecord,
COUNT sum(case when status = 3 then 1 end) as totalrecentactiverecords,
COUNT sum(case when status = 4 then 1 end) as totalemailverifiedrecords
FROM table_user where country=IN
```